# Are Licensing Questions On Topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/creative-commons-and-writing-on-the-web) about the CC license and web writing is a bit murky, but the underlying issue seems to be how to license one's writing on the web.  I understand having licensing questions as they relate to publishing, e-books, etc.  Do we also want to include blogs, wikis, the SE sites, and other websites, unrelated to publishing issues, as on-topic for licensing discussions?  Is this useful to professionals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe licensing questions should be on topic. I understand that this is not a site for lawyers but licensing issues can be discussed in the context of writers helping writers.

Also, this site is about "writing," not "book publishing." Writing is writing whether you are authoring books, e-books, blogs, wikis, or a poem to your dog scribbled on the back of a cocktail napkin. **I see no benefit to excluding *any* media** for the purpose of determining scope.